# Initialize a C++ vector with a variable inital value

Tags: c++, vector

I was coding up a Union find data structure , and was trying to initialize the parent vector with a value parent[i]=i, Is there a way in c++ to initialize the vector like this , that is declaring a vector of size N , and not assigning fixed values to each element, rather position dependent value to each element. (without using any obvious for loops)

```
This is what I was looking for:
  std::vector<int> parent(Initializer);
```

where Initializer is some class or a function.

To try out my hand a bit, I wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Initializer {
private:
    static int i;
public:
    int operator() ()
    {
        return i++;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> parent(Initializer);
    cout << parent[0];
    return 0;
}
```

However I think I have messed up my concepts pretty bad here, and I am not getting what the declaration means, or what it is doing.

Please answer both the questions,

(1) How to initialize a vector with variable initial values.

(2) What exactly is the code I wrote doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a function declaration:

```
vector<int> parent(Initializer);
```

Becasue `Initializer` is a type name, you declared a function `parent` that takes `Initializer` as a (unnamed) parameter and returns `vector<int>`. See [Most vexing parse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

To do what you want, you can do this:

```
std::vector<int> parent(N);    // where N is the size you want
std::iota(parent.begin(), parent.end(), 0);  // fill it with consecutive values
                                             // starting  with 0
```

There's [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) algorithm that you can use to save result of a function (or function object) in a range:

```
std::generate(parent.begin(), parent.end(), Initializer());
```

[**Live demo.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdc38c70e01456bf)

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to initialize some "functionally dependant values " , like i*i or sqrt(i).

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternatives. If you want to initialize the vector with increasing values, then you can use `std::iota`.

```
std::vector<int> vec(size);
std::iota(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), 0);
```

If you want something more general you could use `std::generate`.

```
std::vector<int> vec(size);
int n = 0;
std::generate(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [&n]() {return n++;});
```